# Android Studio not resolving R class. Unable to go to definition

Tags: android, android-studio

I got weird issue after upgrade to Android Studio 3.2

The project is **built successfully, the app is running** but R class stays in red and its not allowing me to do Ctrl + Click to go to definition.

I've already tried Clean Caches and Restart, Clean project, Rebuild project, delete **build** folder.

---

## Answer

After some time, I've download Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13 from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and it works now.

Comment: R is a generated class my studio creates R.java under \AndroidStudioProjects\projectname\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\androidx\versionedparcelable

Answer (score 0):

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml folder and fix any problenms you may have there ( check the other xml folders just in case). Then clean the project, rebuild and sync project with gradle. My app wasn't running because it was unable to resolve R. Tried all the methods you tried first but the problem for me was in the AndroidManifest.xml. Hope this is the solution to your problem.